# Grouped Query with different field values

Tags: mysql, group-by

I use the following query to group year-by-year salaries into one single contract record.

```
SELECT playerid,contractid,term,min(season) as yearone,exp_year,notes
FROM salaries
GROUP BY playerid, contractid
HAVING yearone <= 2014 AND exp_year > 2014
```

As you can see, I group all records on playerid and contractid. All fields in the grouped result have the same data with the exception of "notes" which can either contain a note or be NULL.

What I would like to achieve is one of the following two options:

1. If ANY of the records grouped together contain a note, indicate that not all records were NULL (can be as simple as a 1=note / 0=null)

OR

2. If ANY of the records in the group contain a note, do not include it in the query (i.e. - only query contracts where all records have notes = NULL)

I'm not certain this is possible, but would love some input / guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if any record contains a note, you can write a `case` that returns 1 or 0 depending on having a note or not. Maxing this value will return if there is at least one note. You could also sum it to get the number of notes.

```
SELECT 
  playerid,
  contractid,
  term,
  min(season) as yearone,
  exp_year,
  notes,
  max(case when notes is not null then 1 else 0 end) as HASNOTES,
  sum(case when notes is not null then 1 else 0 end) as NUMBEROFNOTES
FROM salaries
GROUP BY playerid, contractid
HAVING yearone <= 2014 AND exp_year > 2014
```

And obviously you can move that value to the `HAVING` clause, causing the query to not return those records that have a note:

```
HAVING
  max(case when notes is not null then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```